# Does a bouncing ball have a point where it stops all motion before changing direction?

Tags: forces, energy

assume a perfectly vertical plane, smooth surface with no deflection and an elastic ball.
the moment the ball reaches the lower surface, kinetic energy is at maximum
when the ball strikes the lower surface, it then compresses, and some (or all) kinetic energy becomes elastic energy.
when the ball has reached maximum elastic compression, does it momentarily stop?

Comment: *Any* object moving along one dimension that reverses its direction of motion must come to an instantaneous stop.

Comment: If all of its kinetic energy is lost at some instant during the collision, how can it not stop?

Comment: There is a ***deep*** question hidden in your wording, given quantum theory: what is a *point*? As long as you stick to Newtonian physics , you don't have even to think about. No worries.

Comment: Does all the kinetic energy become elastic energy?

Comment: @MARKKAPERA "Does all kinetic energy become potential energy ?" - no, not necessarily. The ball is an extended object not a point particle. So although its KE has a minimum value at some point during the collision, this minimum value is not necessarily zero. See my answer below.

Comment: @gandalf61 , that's why I specified a perfectly vertical plane in my description.  After watching slo-mo videos, I realized wave motion thru the object continues. Thanks for a great response~!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> #### ***Yes, We can do this by applying the work energy theorem, and the mathematical aspect is as follows.***

### **Assumption of some basic parameter:**

- $v$ = Velocity of the ball
- $m$ = Mass of the ball
- $k$ = Spring constant as you can treat the compression of ball similar to spring (ideal) compression
- $\Delta x$ = Compressed length

### **Applying Work Energy Theorem:**

- We can assume the time when *the ball has maximum K.E and is about to touch the ground* as **initial case** and when *the ball is compressed to maximum* extent as **final case**.
- Kinetic Energy (Maximum) = Elastic Energy stored {By W.E.T}

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$$
$$mv^2=k(\Delta x^2)$$

- As can be seen from the expression, all of the K.E will be converted to Elastic Energy, resulting in the ball having velocity $v=0$ at the given instant. Although, because the collision is elastic, it will regain all of the K.E.

#### ***Hope This Helps! Do correct me if I'm wrong.***

Comment: How do you know that *all* of the KE of the ball is converted into elastic energy/potential energy during the collision ? This certainly does not happen if the ball impacts the plane at an oblique angle, since the ball's KE is never zero in that scenario.

Comment: @gandalf61 The scenario provided states that kinetic energy is at its maximum when the ball strikes the lower surface, indicating that the ball's motion is normal to the surface. Additionally, we are just justifying that there is a case where K.E can be zero, not implying that your scenario is incorrect.

Comment: The KE *can* have a minimum value of zero, but it does not *have to* have a minimum value of zero, even when the collision is perpendicular. The answer to "Does a bouncing ball have a point where it stops all motion before changing direction?" is "no, not necessarily".

Comment: @gandalf61 could you mathematically justify it?

Comment: @gandalf61 your answer is only valid if the ball is non rigid...

Comment: The question says that the ball compresses, so I think we can safely assume it is non-rigid. In any case, if the ball is rigid then its KE is constant so it changes direction instantaneously ...

Comment: @gandalf61 but I have even taken the case of compression in my solution as we can treat it similar to spring compression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Acceleration is the instantaneous change in velocity per unit time, and by Newton's second law, it is proportional to the force.  Since it's impossible to have an infinite force, it is also impossible to have an infinite acceleration, and therefore velocity must be continuous with respect to time (i.e., there can be no instantaneous jumps in velocity). So if at one time an object was moving in the downward direction, and then at a later time it was moving in the upward direction, then by the Intermediate Value Theorem there must have been a time in which it was moving neither downward nor upward.  QED.

Comment: This shows that each individual part of the ball is stationary at some point in time during the collision - but how do you know that *all* parts of the ball are stationary *at the same time* ?

Comment: Intermediate Value Theorem can be found where?

Comment: @user45664 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 0):

> Does a bouncing ball have a point where it stops all motion before changing direction?

No, not necessarily. If the ball is moving perpendicular to the plane then there is a point in time at which the *centre of mass* of the ball is stationary, because the velocity of the centre of mass changes continuously from positive to negative, so it must be zero at some point in time. However, this does *not* mean that every part of the ball (which is an extended object, not a point object) is stationary at that time. The kinetic energy of the ball is positive both before and after the collision, so although its KE must have some minimum value during the collision, this minimum value is not necessarily zero (which would be required if every part of the ball was stationary at the same time).